# Mounted Linux OS Drive - Read/Write

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, security, users

I have a Linux OS drive mounted. I know the password (and username, user ID) for the root account and admin account.

How can I mount it or access the files without booting into that operating system?
Is that possible? And yes, I have reason(s) for wanting to do this.

Answer (score 1):

`chroot` is exactly meant for that. You just mount the entries from the target's `/etc/fstab` into their target directories as needed, `mount -t bind` in `/proc` and `/sys`, and then just `chroot /target`.

The one thing that's totally useless, though, is anyone's password.